# Google Calendar Subscription Not Showing Attendees

Tags: calendar, google-calendar-api, icalendar

My site exposes calendar feeds. Here's a simple example:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID;X-RICAL-TZSOURCE=TZINFO:-//com.denhaven2/NONSGML ri_cal gem//EN
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
VERSION:2.0
METHOD:PUBLISH
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTEND;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20180911T150000Z
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20180911T140000Z
ATTENDEE;CN=Tim Scott;CUTYPE=INDIVIDUAL;PARTSTAT=ACCEPTED;ROLE=REQ-PARTIC
 IPANT;X-NUM-GUESTS=0:mailto:tscott@example.com
UID:504332
DESCRIPTION:Attendees:\nTim Scott - tscott@example.com
URL:https://slotted.co/test-glg
SUMMARY:My Event
LOCATION:
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

When I subscribe to this with iCal, I can see the attendees and the description.

However, when I subscribe with Google Calendar, there does not appear to be any way to show either the attendees or the description. Is there something I can do in generating the feed to make this information visible? Or is there something I can advise my users to do?

Answer (score 0):

I'm running into the same issue with the Attendees in Google Calendar via a subscription URL that I'm generating the iCal feed for. I think the spec (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.8.4) might actually prohibit this use of the Attendees field. The language is a bit opaque, but the section I'm referring to is as follows:

> This property is not specified in an
> iCalendar object that specifies only a time zone definition or
> that defines calendar components that are not group-scheduled
> components, but are components only on a single user's calendar.

If your case is like mine where users are subscribing to the calendar feed, I'm thinking this would fall under the "only on a single user's calendar" portion of the above statement. My reading of the spec may be off-base, but I've seen many people complaining about this same thing on the Internet for years without any sort of resolution.